# SixSigma -> ss.study.ca Error: Unknown parameters: binwidth

Tags: r, qcc

I have tried to do some capability studies using SixSigma package with function: `ss.study.ca()`. However I get an error:

```
Error: Unknown parameters: binwidth
```

Even trying the example:

```
ss.study.ca(ss.data.ca$Volume, rnorm(40, 753, 3), 
            LSL = 740, USL = 760, T = 750, alpha = 0.05, 
            f.sub = "Winery Project")
```

is not working as well and gives the same error

does anyone have the same problem with `SixSigma` package?

Additionally I have tried to go for `qcc` package and i found there is a function for process
capability six-pack plots (`process.capability.sixpack()`). This function is stated in the publication [http://www.stat.unipg.it/luca/Rnews_2004-1-pag11-17.pdf](http://www.stat.unipg.it/luca/Rnews_2004-1-pag11-17.pdf/%22here%22) but not available at the moment ...

What kind of package would help me to perform the capability studies?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you will have to contact the Six Sigma folks on this one, they make a call to `stat_density` with the `binwidth` parameter, which I am guessing was once ok but now is not.

Comment: Kids, these days. Can't seem to use a search engine: https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Exactly i have tried `qcc` package, however the process capability six-pack plots, (`process.capability.sixpack()`) which i need is somehow not available any more